# The connect() C function can't connect with my router, but I can connect with it using javascript ajax call

Tags: c, sockets, winsock2

I'm coding a C application to connect with a router. The router does not filter any incoming connections, neither is behind any firewall. My problem is the C function "connect" returns SOCKET_ERROR, but the error message I get calling perror when this happens is: No error (¿?). That probably means I'm looking in the wrong direction (the place where perror gets the error msg from is not the place I'm interested in).

**UPDATE**: As suggested in comments, I called WSAGetLastError(), which returns 10061 ([connection refused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

At same time, I have a web application that connects with the router and send it a json message via AJAX call. No problem at all. Using the same IP and same port to connect with.

If helps, the `connect` function I'm using is defined at WinSock2.h. Working with Windows 7 Home Premium and Visual Studio 2010.

Those are what I consider relevant parts of the code (**UPDATE**: Added the missing part of socket initialization)

```
// Enters here

#ifdef WIN32
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int error   = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData);
    if(error != 0) return false;
    if(LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 0)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
#endif

struct addrinfo hints;
struct addrinfo *m_data;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

// hostname is a char * containing my IP, in the same subnetwork than the router, 
// and I'm going to connect with 192.168.90.1 (connection correctly open) and port 5555
port = "5555";


getaddrinfo(hostname, port, &hints, &m_data);
int m_socket = socket(m_data->ai_family, m_data->ai_socktype, m_data->ai_protocol);

// more stuff here

if (connect(m_socket, (struct sockaddr *)m_data->ai_addr, m_data->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    // I get "connection error: no error" here. Why?
    perror("connection error"); 
    closesocket(m_socket);
    return false;
}
```

So, why can I connect via AJAX call but the C connect function returns SOCKET_ERROR? Any clues?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Use `WSAGetLastError` to get the error code.

Comment: Getting 10061, which according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx means "Connection refused". But the ajax connections are working fine.

Comment: Add the missing code that initializes the socket.

Comment: Add `hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;` ?

Comment: Try initializing Winsock version 2.2 `WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);` ?

Comment: Added ai_protocol. Same error. I'll try David suggestion (and snippet), and event I'll change the computer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the protocol.

```
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
```

And also, you should try initializing Winsock to version 2.2.

Snippet of how I connect using Winsock.

```
#ifdef WIN32
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int error   = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if(error != 0) return false;
    if(LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
#endif


SOCKADDR_IN sin;
LPHOSTENT lpHost = gethostbyname(hostname);
bool bRet = false;

if(NULL != lpHost) {
    m_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(5555);
    sin.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = *(unsigned __int32*)lpHost->h_addr;

    if(connect(m_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&sin, 
        sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        perror("connection error");
        closesocket(m_socket);
    } else bRet = true;
}

return bRet;
```

Comment: I forgot to paste the socket initialization part. But anyway, many thanks for the snippet!